# What happens when a phone is rooted?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

which files in the phone are changed when a phone is rooted. Is any app is installed during this? Can we manually change apps in phone to have root permissions?

Answer (score 0):

"Can we change apps in phone to have root permission?" If the app was built to use root permissions, you need them to run the app. Unless said app is open source, you cannot modify it to use root permissions. I also do not believe an app can root a device. You must have an in depth knowledge of the OS to make an app to root a phone. Which files are changed?

I dont know. I do know that you sound like someone who wants to root ur phone. The process is probably more complicated than changing a few lines of code in some remote, hard to find file in your device. I suggest learning more on the topic and on already-available solutions if this is you. If not, well, ignore this last paragraph :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question. Normally rooting installs an app to control the allocation of the root permission to apps that request it and also adds the root (or super user) binaries to the device therefore enabling it. You cannot change an app to request root but you need to change it at the source to do so. Which is a question for [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score -1):

Basically just exploiting the system to allow arbitrary code execution, or code not from the developers.

Check out this article: [Android Rooting: A Developer's Guide](http://seasonofcode.com/posts/android-rooting-a-developer-s-guide.html)

Comment: You can execute any code any when on android using the ADB shell. So this isn't very accurate. But along the right lines.